# Packages and Classpath

Tags: java, package, classpath

I have created a package in the following way, and stored the Simple1.java file in d:\p\javas

Simple1.java

```
package mypack;
public class Simple1
{
    public static void display()
    {
        System.out.println("Welcome to package");
    }
}
```

i compiled it using -d switch:
    **d:\p\javas> javac -d d:\p\notes Simple1.java**

and i got the mypack package under the P\Notes folder in D Drive.

I want to set a permanent classpath for this package so that i can access it from anywhere in my system, and i tried doing so using the environment variables.

Now, when i try importing this package in another file which is stored at another location in my system, using:

import mypack.*;

and try accessing the Simple1.class file, i get error.

the code for new java file is:

packDemo.java

```
import mypack.*;
class packDemo
{
    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
        Simple1 s= new Simple1();
        s.display();
    }
}
```

Could you please help me resolving the issue, and kindly let me know the exact way of setting the classpath also. 
I want to set permanent classpath for both the locations i am using to store my .java files.

Comment: what kind of error you are getting?please ask your question with some more clarity!

Comment: The error says: packDemo.java:1 error: package mypack does not exist

Comment: You have not set the classpath correctly try to check your enviroment variable if possible post here

Comment: This is the command you have to use  set CLASSPATH=your path;

Comment: Okay! I created a Classpath variable under system variables in Environment Variables for mypack as: D\P\Notes, now the packDemo.java gets compiled, but while trying to execute it i again  get an error that says: Could not find or load main class packDemo

Comment: I don't want to use temporary classpath, i already mentioned that i want to create permanent classpath for all the locations in my system that i use to store my .java files

Comment: give the path upto package that means D\P\Notes\mypack

Comment: still i get the same error

Comment: Refer this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

Comment: i have referred to this doc earlier also, it didn't resolve my issue. Just let me know one thing... Do i need to put all my .class files at the same path if i create a classpath variable??? Because i have saved packDemo at another location and mypack package is at another location.

Comment: I have posted answer please check

Answer (score 1):

1.Simple1.class file is stored in below directory upto this is fine

```
d:\p\notes
```

2.set the classpath in environment variable as follows

```
variable:ClASSPATH
value:d:\p\notes
```

3.Now navigate to packDemo.java folder compile the packDemo.java using below switch

```
javac packDemo.java
```

4.run the .class file

```
java packDemo
```

This will work fine without any problems

Comment: yes i did the same, and it worked fine till step 3, but when i run the .class file, i again get the error: could not find or load main class packDemo

Comment: While setting environment variable value are you giving semicolon at the end?

Comment: Actually i have create the CLASSPATH variable under user variables as it did not exist previously, and the variable value contains only single path, so i did not give the semi colon initially

Comment: And when i added the semicolon in the classpath, my file doesn't compile now, it cannot find the packaged class.

Comment: It is not necessary but try to put and compile.Your problem is with classpath that means it not setting well because of that your getting  the following error "could not find or load main class"

Comment: What i feel is once we set the classpath variable value, JVM tries finding all the .class files at the same path that has been given in the classpath, may be that's why it is able to compile the packDemo.java file but not able to run it, because packDemo.class is stored at another location.

Comment: You are right!we should have .class file of packDemo  in this folder d:\p\notes.

Comment: this would of course work @Naveen. now the packDemo.class is part of the package itself, i wanted it to be a part of another package only as i have made Simple1 as a public class.